# meteor - Account.forgotPassword not working, getting internal server error

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm getting an annoyingly vague Internal server error in my meteor Accounts.forgotPassword callback. I have accounts-base installed and I know my SMTP settings (defined on the server in Meteor.startup) are fine because I can call Email.send successfully.

Here's the code. It's pretty generic, so I'm not at all sure what could be going wrong. Any thoughts?

```
var options = {};
options.email = "my@email.address";

Accounts.forgotPassword(options, function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log("error: "+err.reason);
    } else {
        console.log("Success!");
    }
});
```

Comment: `Accounts.forgotPassword` belongs to `accounts-password` package. [See here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L214).

Comment: Thanks BlazeSahlzen. I have accounts-password installed, so it's not that. I ended up writing a custom password reset script, but it would be great to figure out what's actually going on.

Comment: @aragorn23 have you fixed this issue? It looks like we two are the only ones who've had this :)

Answer (score 2):

One simply needs to overwrite the `Accounts` package's email template's `from` function:

`Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.from = () => 'me <me@mydomain.com>';`

It's future safe to also:

`Accounts.emailTemplates.from = () => 'me <me@mydomain.com>';`